# ORA-12514 error with JDBC thin client to Express 11.2

Tags: jdbc, ora-12514

1. SQLPLUS connects to the Express 11.2 'XE' service running on Windows 7 using 'sqlplus hr/hr@XE'. 
   Express 11.2, SQLPLUS and Java App all are running on the PROD10 Windows 7 workstation.
2. Java app using JDBC thin client receives the below error using this connect string: jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@//PROD10:1521/xe:
   Listener refused the connection with the following error:
   ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
3. Using ojdbc6.jar type 4 driver with jdk1.60_27.
4. 'lsnrctl services' reports the below:
   LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 05-NOV-2017 16:22:19

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER 
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=TIGER2)(PORT=50085))
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully

5. tnsnames.ora contains:
   XE =
   (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = TIGER2)(PORT = 1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SERVER = DEDICATED)
     (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
   )
   )
   ORCL =
   (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = TIGER2)(PORT = 1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SID = ORCL)
   )
   )
   EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
   (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
   )
   (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SID = PLSExtProc)
     (PRESENTATION = RO)
   )
   )
   ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
   (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST = 
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
   ) 
   (CONNECT_DATA = 
     (SID = CLRExtProc) 
     (PRESENTATION = RO) 
   ) 
   )
6. listener.ora contains:
   SID_LIST_LISTENER =
   (SID_LIST =
   (SID_DESC =
     (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
     (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
     (PROGRAM = extproc)
   )
   (SID_DESC =
     (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
     (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
     (PROGRAM = extproc)
   )
   )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = TIGER2)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, this is the [same issue](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4095485) posted on JDBC forum and is resolved.